# ODBC Lib Not Found When Running As Service

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, informix, systemd

I have a script that I use that executes queries against an Informix database using pyodbc. The script runs fine if I try and run it as a shell, but when I set it up to run as a service in systemd I receive the following error:

```
Jul 23 21:52:39 <server name redacted> database_to_domo.py[16368]: pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli/iclis09b.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I originally received this error when attempting to run it from the shell but fixed the issue by making myself the owner of the /opt/IBM directory and its children.

I tried to fix it when running as a service by setting permissions to 777, but that did not work. Here is my config for the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=UCCX data uploader for Domo

[Service]
User=A683040
Environment=INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql
Environment=INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=$INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts
WorkingDirectory=/home/a683040/uccx-domo-data
ExecStart=/home/a683040/uccx-domo-data/database_to_domo.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The library exists at the path where it says it is not found. Here is my output for ldd:

```
$ ldd /opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc06b9b000)
 libifgls.so => /opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql/libifgls.so (0x00007f39b479b000)
 libifglx.so => /opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql/libifglx.so (0x00007f39b4599000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f39b4297000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f39b4093000)
 libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f39b3e5c000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f39b3c40000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f39b3872000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f39b4da7000)
 libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f39b366f000)
```

Comment: Maybe your service is not picking up the environment or is using a different python (32 vs 64) to run the script.
What if you change the 'ExecStart' in the service to something like 'strace -o /tmp/trace.txt python ...../database_to_domo.py'  to get a trace of what is really trying to do. Also, not that it matters here, but your DSN should use 'iclit09b.so' rather than 'iclis09b.so' (the 's' is for single thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running ldd on iclis09b.so as root, instead of my login user, I got different results:

```
$ sudo ldd -v /opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9d6fd000)
 libifgls.so => not found
 libifglx.so => not found
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9c2b1ef000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9c2afeb000)
 libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f9c2adb4000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9c2ab98000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9c2a7ca000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9c2b8aa000)
 libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f9c2a5c7000)
```

To resolve this issue I added the following symlinks and the script will now run as a service.

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql/libifgls.so /lib64/libifgls.so
$ sudo ln -s /opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql/libifglx.so /lib64/libifglx.so
$ sudo ln -s /opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql/libifgls.so /opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli/libifgls.so
$ sudo ln -s /opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql/libifglx.so /opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli/libifglx.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually have symlinks created but still get 'not found' on libifglx.so and libifgls.so. Also I've added search paths to /etc/environment and /etc/profile and I see it running `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but can't run python script from shell until I make export variables manually. Systemd service is not starting as well.

The correct solution is to use the explicit path `/opt/IBM/informix` instead of `$INFORMIXDIR` in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and other variables. For some reason, nested variables were not applying.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was the missing rpm package. This means if you have this sort of trouble try: `apt install rpm` and reinstall informix package